# Prior probability in HMM

Tags: machine-learning, probability-theory, hidden-markov-models

[image: HMM model]

This is the HMM model considered in the question
[image: Emission probability matrix]

And this is the emission probabilities for the respective states. There are two emission values, bringing an umbrella and not bringing an umbrella.

**Description of the question:**

The question considered the *initial state as sunny*.
On *day 2*, the person *brought an umbrella*. 
On *day 3*, the person *didn't carry an umbrella*.

We have to find the probability that it's foggy on 3rd day.

Given: Prior probability of the caretaker carrying an umbrella is 0.5.

According to me, the answer to this question was addition of the terms in the red circles.

Where α<sub>1</sub> = 0.8 * 0.1, α<sub>2</sub> = 0.05 * 0.8, α<sub>3</sub> = 0.15 * 0.3

**Problem I faced:**
But the answer included dividing the answer I got by (0.5)<sup>2</sup>. That is, I guess they are dividing by the prior probability two times for the two transitions, but I'm not clear as to why they are dividing.
[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s_2,s_3$ be the states on the second and third days, and let $x_2,x_3$ be the indicators of carrying an umbrella on these days. Then
$$
\newcommand{\Sunny}{\mathit{Sunny}}
\newcommand{\Rainy}{\mathit{Rainy}}
\newcommand{\Foggy}{\mathit{Foggy}}
\newcommand{\Yes}{\mathit{Yes}}
\newcommand{\No}{\mathit{No}}
\Pr[s_3 = \Foggy \mid s_1 = \Sunny, x_2 = \Yes, x_3 = \No] =
\frac{\Pr[s_3 = \Foggy, x_2 = \Yes, x_3 = \No \mid s_1 = \Sunny]}{\Pr[x_2 = \Yes, x_3 = \No \mid s_1 = \Sunny]}
$$
It seems you might have forgotten the denominator.